# Convert multidimensional array into single array with key and values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**This is my array,**

```
 array
           (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Invoice_id] => 1
                    [Customer_Name] => Abcd Ltd
                    [Order_Created] => 2018-02-07
                    [Order_Delivery_Date] => 2018-02-17
                    [State_Code] => 35
                    [CGST] => 212.5
                    [SGST] => 212.5
                    [IGST] => 0
                    [Total_Amount] => 8925
                )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Invoice_id] => 2
                [Customer_Name] => Johnson and Sons
                [Order_Created] => 2018-02-07
                [Order_Delivery_Date] => 2018-02-17
                [State_Code] => 35
                [CGST] => 2975
                [SGST] => 2975
                [IGST] => 0
                [Total_Amount] => 124950
            )
    )
```

**How to convert this array like below,**

```
array
    (
    array("invoice_id" => "1", "customer_name" => "Abcd Ltd", "order_created" => 2018-02-07, "delivery_date" => 2018-02-17, "state_code" => 35, "cgst" =>212.5, "sgst" =>212.5, "igst" =>0, "total_amount" =>8925),
    array("invoice_id" => "2", "customer_name" => "Johnson and Sons", "order_created" => 2018-02-07, "delivery_date" => 2018-02-17, "state_code" => 35, "cgst" =>2975, "sgst" =>2975, "igst" =>512.5, "total_amount" =>124950)
    );
```

Comment: Please format code as code. / What have you tried?

Comment: the output you talking is also multi dimensional array! I think you are not clear on basics.

Comment: Do you think that writing the whole of your question in bold will attract more attention to your question? Well, it probably attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You already have it in the format you want, they are just in different ways of displaying arrays, except that your arrays are indexed by keys, if you really want to unindex it use this `$newArray = array_values($array)`

Comment: _"already have it in the format"_, look at the keys. They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to change keys of your array :

```
foreach ($array as $k => $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        unset($array[$k][$key]) ; // remove old key
        $array[$k][strtolower($key)] = $value ; // add new one
    }
}
```

Then `"Invoice_id"` keys will be `"invoice_id"`, and so on.